# Combining duplicate IDs with different data in each row

Tags: mysql, database

this is my first time on this site. I'm relatively new to MySQL.
currently, I'm trying to make a database/group of tables with data from a soccer league. The issue I'm running into is combining the data of players that have changed teams. In the data, the players who have changed teams during the season get data for each team they played for. So far I've used this

```
SELECT player_name, 
AVG(`Playing Time 90s`) AS `Playing Time 90s`,
AVG(`Per 90 Minutes Gls`) AS `Per 90 Minutes Gls`,
AVG(`Per 90 Minutes Ast`) AS `Per 90 Minutes Ast`,
AVG(`Per 90 Minutes G+A`) AS `Per 90 Minutes G+A`,
AVG(`Per 90 Minutes G-PK`) AS `Per 90 Minutes G-PK`,
AVG(`Per 90 Minutes G+A-PK`) AS `Per 90 Minutes G+A-PK`,
AVG(`Per 90 Minutes xG`) AS `Per 90 Minutes xG`,
AVG(`Per 90 Minutes xG`) AS `Per 90 Minutes xG`,
AVG(`Expected xA`) AS `Expected xA`,
AVG(`Expected npxG+xA`) AS `Expected npxG+xA`,
AVG(`Per 90 Minutes xG`) AS `Per 90 Minutes xG`,
AVG(`Per 90 Minutes xA`) AS `Per 90 Minutes xA`,
AVG(`Per 90 Minutes xG+xA`) AS `Per 90 Minutes xG+xA`,
AVG(`Per 90 Minutes npxG`) AS `Per 90 Minutes npxG`,
AVG(`Per 90 Minutes npxG+xA`) AS `Per 90 Minutes npxG+xA`,
SUM(`Playing Time MP`) as `Playing Time MP`,
SUM(`Playing Time Starts`) as `Playing Time Starts`,
SUM(`Playing Time Min`) as `Playing Time Min`,
SUM(`Playing Time Starts`) as `Playing Time Starts`
FROM prem.standard22
group by player_name 
;
```

to average or sum the data in each column.
Is there a more efficient way to do this?
I have 10 tables to go through and it's going to take forever.
(Please give advice on how to better format my questions. or leave feedback for anything I did wrong)
Thanks

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You could simplify the question to only be about the main issue which I think is 'how do I get all the data for a player across multiple tables.'  - I think probably UNION all the tables before analysing.